# Calculation for a variation of hours

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to programming and I am learning to program in C++, I am having some trouble trying to work out what would be the best way to attack this solution for a console game I am making, so basically I have 3 games that go for 5 hours each, and any game after that will go for 4 hours, once I get the amount of the games the user wants to play, basically I want to work out the total amount of hours the games will take to play.

How do i go about calculating the first 3 games multiply 5 hours and anything after that by 4 hours if there are more than 3 games being played?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Is this a simple math question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned int n_hours(unsigned int n_games) {
  if (n_games < 4) {
    return n_games*5;
  } else {
    return (n_games-3)*4 + 15; 
    //return n_games*4+3; //less straightforward to understand
  }
}
```